# Lua Program Ends Prematurely

Tags: lua

I am fairly new to programming in Lua, and have downloaded several interpreters. My problem is that as soon as my computer finishes executing my program, it closes the window. In other words, a program like
print("Hello World")
stays open for less than half a second. Obviously, this is a large obstacle in my attempts to learn lua. I have already attempted to use a different interpreter, and although there are several available online, I experience the problem I described above with all of them but one, which is a bit outdated, and thus cannot execute some of the programs I write. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. 
By the way, I am opening the program by dragging it over lua.exe, or whatever program I am using.

Comment: Just finish your program with `io.read()` - you will need to press `Enter` to exit.

Answer (score 3):

> I am opening the program by dragging it over lua.exe, or whatever program I am using.

That's your issue: in Windows, opening a command line program like that will open up a command prompt and then close when the command is done.

You should be running your command-line Lua programs from a command prompt.  Here's what this looks like in a Unix-y system:

```
$ cat hello.lua
print "Hello from Lua!"

$ lua hello.lua
Hello from Lua!
```

On Windows, it might look something more like:

```
> C:\Programs\Lua5.1\lua.exe hello.lua
Hello from Lua!
```

You can open your command prompt by clicking Start, choosing Run, and then running `cmd.exe`.  Then, since you are already in a command prompt, the window won't close.

Comment: Thank you both for your tips. I have been wondering how to create an equivalent for pause<nul in lua, and starting my program through command prompt was definitely what I had been looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Press the <kbd>Start</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> key, a dialog as shown below will open. Type "**`cmd`**" in the box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click **OK**.

[image: Run]

After the next terminal opens(something as shown below); you can simply type `lua` followed by file path/name that you want to execute.

[image: Command]